# Can't update then insert in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write PHP code to update a value once it exist, and if it doesn't then insert it. Part of this function works which is the insert part however the update doesn't seem to work my code is below:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['Track'];
$user = $_GET['User'];
$rating = $_GET['Rating'];
include("connect.php");
$query = "UPDATE `rating` SET `rating` = '$rating' WHERE track_id = '$id' AND user_id = '$user' AND rating_set=NOW()";
$sth = $dbc->query($query);
$rows = $sth->rowCount();  

if ($rows == 0) {
$query = "INSERT INTO rating values ('$id','$rating','$user',NOW())";
$results = $dbc->query($query); 
$rows = $results->rowCount(); 
}

/* output in necessary format */

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
echo "(" . json_encode($rows) . ")";


$dbc = null;
?>
```

Comment: insert replae/insert ... on duplicate key update

Comment: What data type has `rating_set`?

Comment: `rating_set` most probably is the fault here because you try to match it by current time, im pretty sure inserted time differs from current time so you never getting a match.

Comment: Are you trying to do this: `$query = "UPDATE rating SET rating = '$rating', rating_set=NOW() WHERE track_id = '$id' AND user_id = '$user'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query can't work.

You are only updating data where `rating_set` is exactly `NOW()`. That will most likely not fit on any data record. You probably only want to use the `date` part.

Comment: you are not forced to, if you use all of them

Comment: how can I then save the time when the query has been updated?

Comment: @KernElliott: You should use NOW() to **set** the data, but you put it in the `where` clause to **filter** the data you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

you are using NOW() in update query, which gives current time. Which will never be same!!! try removing '....AND rating_set=NOW()' from your update query.

Comment: how can I then save the time when the query has been updated?

Comment: In your original update query  you are only updating 'rating' field. You are not updating 'rating_set', instead you are using it in 'where' clause. you should write your update query like..... "UPDATE `rating` SET `rating` = '$rating', `rating_set` = NOW() WHERE track_id = '$id' AND user_id = '$user'"